# Page number position in memoir class

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I would like the page numbers to be found at the bottom, on the outside of the page and at the same time, in the header I would like there to be the title of the chapter without the number. I'm new to this utilization of LaTeX, so I tried to find a way but I only managed to have the page numbers at the top, next to the header. This is what I have done:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[a5paper, total={4.3in,6in}]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }

\chapterstyle{dash}

\chapter{Material girl (in a Material World)}
blablablabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can mark your code as code and make it easier to read by indenting it by four spaces or clicking the `{}` button. Contrary to other stackexchange sites we don't run MathJax so that `$\LaTeX$` will not be rendered in the body of your question (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/35864 and all the linked questions for a bit of background why).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own page style, for instance

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper, total={4.3in,6in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage} % page number on the bottom right
\makepagestyle{pter}
\makeoddhead{pter}{\itshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeevenhead{pter}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeoddfoot{pter}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{pter}{\thepage}{}{}

\pagestyle{pter}
\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Material girl (in a Material World)}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Each declaration `\make`{`odd`|`even`}{`head`|`foot`} takes four arguments: the page style name and then what goes on the left, center and right of the header or footer.

In the chapter starting page, the `plain` page style is used.